# Pagination from an external link

Tags: php

Ok I have no clue how to do this, I have a pagination system for a MySQL query but am stuck in a process of thinking of how I would turn a external link result of 20 (or even if I did 50) into pages of 10 results per page?

the code im using right now is as follows:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/sentuamsg/uploads?max-results=20';
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
$i=0;
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
  $media = $entry->children('media', true);
  $watch = (string)$media->group->player->attributes()->url;
  $thumbnail = (string)$media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes()->url;

parse_str( parse_url( $watch, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );

echo "presentation of the result goes here";

$i++; if($i==5) { 

$i=0; 
 } 
}
```

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Youtube Gdata API has a variable called "start-index".
You can create a based php function to detect the current page and put into the variable + 1.

Would be like...

**Current page...**

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/sentuamsg/uploads?max-results=20&start-index=1

**Second page...**

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/sentuamsg/uploads?max-results=20&start-index=21

And that will be the logic. Each page, +20 into the value. If you wanna show 20 results, for example.